# ffmpeg - convert background to black?

Tags: ffmpeg, alpha

**the basic problem**
convert all pixels in all frames of a source video to black if they have a white value below a certain threshold and output the results as a series of static images with no transparency.

**my solution so far**
i am able to do this with a two-step process :

1. convert pixels below the threshold to transparent using ffmpeg's `colorkey` filtre, outputting a series as PNG.
2. use imagemagick to convert the PNG to JPEG.

*this approach is very slow.*  ideally i'd like to do everything in one go, within ffmpeg.

the reason i haven't been able to do that so far is that the resulting transparency isn't discarded (as i'd hoped) when outputting to non-transparent formats like JPG, even if i try to 'discard' the alpha layer beforehand using combinations of `split` and `lutrgb` ; the resulting JPEGs still resemble the original images.

my current filter chain :

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -i input.mp4 -f lavfi -i color=c=white \
    -filter_complex "[0:v]format=gray[src];
        [1][src]scale2ref[white][vid];
        [vid][white]blend=all_mode=multiply:shortest=1,colorkey=black:0.95" %05d.png
```

Comment: Apply the premultiply filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

credit for this answer really should go to @Gyan, whose comment above was enough to set me on the right track to finding a solution.

the '[premultiply filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#premultiply)' mentioned by Gyan applies an 'alpha premultiply effect' to your video. for those of you who don't know what an 'alpha premultiply effect' is [as i didn't], of all of the articles i read, [this one](https://limnu.com/premultiplied-alpha-primer-artists) was most informative. the description of the filter mentioned in the ffmpeg filters documentation, even more terse and cryptic than usual for ffmpeg docs, doesn't really explain how to use the filter ; through trial and error [and qwant], i found the expression that finally did the job for me :

*{...rest-of-filter-chain}*`,premultiply=inplace=1"`